# Is it possible to toggle disabled in a form element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I love JQuery as much as the next person but I want to accomplish this task in JavaScript only please. I've been scouring the internet and all I can find is JQuery solutions and a couple of broken non-working JavaScript ones. [This](http://www.annedorko.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/demo.html) is the cleanest one I could find but it doesn't seem to be working for anyone, but it does seem very old. I can't even wrap my brain around how it works, with a variable being set as an assignment.

Anyway, I put the code in a [`JsFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/74n3rxu7/) so it is easy to manipulate.

Is this just one of those tasks that are overly complicated in JS but then JQuery comes in and completely simplifies it??

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this is just wierd in any language:
`updateToggle = checkbox.checked ? toggle.disabled=true : toggle.disabled=false;` Please dont assign in ternaries or I swear to god I will hunt you down.

Comment: I updated my answer to elaborate a bit...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

...   * YES *

```
element.disabled = !element.disabled;
```

What this does should be pretty obvious, but maybe you are new to JS or programming in general so I will try to explain a few basic things wrong with your code:

### Ternaries is for assignment

Indeed you do assign to a variable but it is never used, maybe you meant something like this

```
element.disabled = element.disabled ? false : true;
```

Though this would probably work it is still way too verbose, you are a programmer, think smart!

### boolean negate

And thats where `!` (boolean negate) comes in to play, since you are toggling a boolean, you might as well just negate the current state with the not/negate operator eg.

```
element.disabled = !element.disabled;
```

this is pretty common and exists in most if not all programming languages, in JS it automagically converts the value to boolean true/false, you should read up on type coercion in javascript, if you are not already familiar with it.

### And why element.disabled assignment changes the state

I guess this is implementation specific, but i would assume that internally javascript uses getter/setters, though they don't exist in javascript...Yet, this will change with ECMA6!